# What do you call this thing that comes with any Apple product

Tags: image-identification

I bought a MacBook Pro, and it came with this thing:

[image]

I don't know how to use it or where should I stick it, that is why I need to ask about it in any Apple forum. Unfortunately, I don't even know the name of it. What is this called?

Comment: It's a sticker. You stick it anywhere you like. It's a "fan" item and not required for your new computer in any way. Use it like you did with other stickers when you were a child. (See, SE saves you a post in another forum... ^_^)

Comment: Others have wondered what to do with them before: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3010175 http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1691978

Comment: @Stephie, "throw them in the garbage".... priceless.

Comment: iCult subscription indicator aka, an apple logo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As FumbleFingers said in a comment:

> Some people might call it a [decal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decal) (2. A decorative sticker) Amazon sells them as [decal stickers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Macbook-decal-sticker-White-Laptop/dp/B006RJVNRM/ref=lp_430489031_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1432036473&sr=1-2).

My immediate thought (even before seeing the image) was "decal".

"Sticker" is a great word and it is perfectly accurate but "[decal](https://www.google.com/search?q=logo%20decal&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=GEBbVdXzLIWDsAWN1oLoBw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg&biw=1111&bih=799#tbm=isch&q=decal)" (Google Image search) has the added meaning (in my head, at least) of being a simple image, often a logo.

Comment: I thought decals were ones without adhesive on the back? That people buy to stick to walls etc.?

Comment: @starsplusplus : Or the ones that must be soaked in water to loosen from the paper backings. I agree with your comment.

Comment: The Amazon link you posted has the product under the "Skin Stickers" category, it's just the people selling the "decal" that named it that

Answer (score 25):

I think they are [stickers:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sticker)

> - One that sticks, as an adhesive label or patch. (AHD)

[Apple stickers](https://www.google.it/search?q=apple%20stickers&biw=768&bih=909&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=uxZbVb_XNeeC7gakwoCgAw&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgrc=_)

Comment: Some people might call it a [**decal**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/decal) *(2. A decorative sticker)* Amazon sell them as [decal stickers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Macbook-decal-sticker-White-Laptop/dp/B006RJVNRM/ref=lp_430489031_1_2?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1432036473&sr=1-2).

Comment: I'm with @FumbleFingers I call them decals, which have the added meaning (in my head, anyway) of being related to a company's logo.

Comment: @Catija - you could make an answer  so it become more visible to users.

Comment: But FumbleFingers was the one who posted it first, didn't want to steal any thunder.

Comment: well, ask him what he would like to do.

Comment: @Catija: You're welcome to post ***decal*** as an answer. I'd normally use ***sticker*** myself, which is why I've only mentioned the alternative in a comment, while upvoting Josh61's answer here. Or he could edit it into his own answer - I really don't mind one way or the other. All that really matters is that OP and future visitors should easily be able to see that ***stickers*** is the most widely-used term (I'm certain that's the case, so our votes should reflect that).

Comment: I think Americans use *decal* these days to refer to higher-quality, more permanent appliqués, regardless of whether they are attached with decalcomania or with adhesives. *Stickers* are [for schoolchildren](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Sticker_window_amsterdam01.jpg) (except *bumper stickers*), or obnoxious marketing campaigns that plaster telephone poles and fence posts with them, whereas *decals* are for your model airplane or [bigger toys](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Veemax_Mk_IVB_1970_Formula_Vee.JPG).

Comment: For me decal specifically implies "without adhesive" so there is far from a consensus among "Americans"

Comment: "Decal" is a term for a specific technology, namely creating a waterproof image on waterproof paper that, after immersion in water, can be slid off onto some other, usually flat, surface to which it will adhere quite like something painted directly onto the surface.  There is no additional adhesive involved, which there is with a thicker, less-fragile "sticker".

Answer (score 9):

To be even more precise, that's a *decal sheet* since it contains more than one decal (or sticker).

It's Apple's invitation to you to express your love and fealty to their brand. In the wild, I have often seen those decals on vehicles, file cabinets, and coffee mugs.

However, one is also free to put them into the trash or recycling in accord with local laws and capabilities.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that you can toss the evil Apple's stickers. -- sent from my iPhone

Comment: Seen them as a disguise on a Toshiba computer :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's just a sticker. I don't think it has an official name.

I use one of these stickers to identify which external hard drive is used to backup my macbook.

Or you could stick them on your Subaru.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//ell.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: In the mean time, continue with what you are doing. Make comments in answers.  @DCShannon you did a nice job of making this into a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Originally **adhesive decal** was used for those that had pre-applied glue but [sticker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticker) has become a synonym even though it is more closely associated with pressure sensitive glues (rather than water or heat activated glues).

As mentioned in an answer this is a sheet as it contains more than one [decal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decal).

[Decal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decal) implies some form of decoration or information and can be affixed in a multitude of ways, and this comes from the French word [decalcomania](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decalcomania).  -